# Angular grid not showing values fetched by Angular resource

Tags: angularjs, ng-grid, ngresource

I have a simple ng-grid that should show a table of users fetched as JSON data:

```
<div class="gridStyle" ng-grid="gridOptions" ng-controller="GridDemoCtrl"></div>

angular.module('grid-demo', ['ngGrid', 'ngResource'])
  .controller('GridDemoCtrl', ['$scope', 'UserRes', function($scope, UserRes) {
    $scope.users = UserRes.query();
    $scope.gridOptions = {
      data: 'users',
      columnDefs: [
        {field:'name', displayName:'Name'},
        {field:'email', displayName:'Email'}
      ]
    };
  }])

  .factory('UserRes', ['$resource', function($resource) {
    return $resource('/site/users.json');
  }])
;
```

I'm fetching the users using ngResource, but they do not appear in the table. I can see the JSON data coming back from the AJAX request. I put a breakpoint inside the resource code, and I can see the data being handled in an internal callback. It just doesn't update the grid when it comes back. I'm new at Angular; am I missing something? Any suggestions much appreciated.

Comment: Check out this q http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23919962/ng-grid-doesnt-populate-with-angular-resource

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PLease see here http://plnkr.co/edit/C7QvLS?p=preview

move your controller above `ng-grid` directive

```
 <div ng-controller="GridDemoCtrl">
    <div class="gridStyle" ng-grid="gridOptions" ></div>
   </div>
```

Comment: Thanks! That fixed it. I thought I had tried that, but I guess not. I assume the problem is that the grid wasn't in the controller's scope the way I had it.